# After adding 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01' we are facing issues while creating sign APK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, material-design, android-support-library

Here are the errors which we are facing:

[Gradle Error](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Em1RrBmHONEHdK54kbKKSPBfhjetU5qM)

[These dependencies we have added](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10pgUI4xLjPW4SWKhjqXwVBYQl4oGhrgE)

[Configurations](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18F9EAUq8JlvhKiG68w6cLWoUPpAKr_hY/view)

Answer (score 0):

We have removed all the support libs references and migrate to **androidx** throughout the project.

Issue has been resolved :)